# Back-end validations using commons validator with Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons, validation, apache-karaf

I am new to Spring and Apache commons Validator, and I need to validate a POJO of user details like address and other general details.

I have tried searching the same on Google but I am getting confused with UI and Back-End validations which are described in those.

Can any one please help me knowing the same or getting some good reference from where I can read and implement the same?

Also please note I need to create this functionality as an OSGI bundle and deploy on Apache Karaf, so in case you are helping me with this please keep this thing in mind.

Comment: Is it necessary to use Apache commons Validator? Spring MVC has its own [validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/validation.html)

Comment: @Ilya : i want to avoid "ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "field.required");" for each field, i just want to have a single call passing a bean to validator and for validation criteria i want an xml or say a property file from where i can modify may validation requirements and do not want to change validation implementation